# How to save x/y coordinate of a movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hello I am almost done with a project in AS3, but the last thing that I need is a save/load function.

I only need to save the "x" of a single movie clip and have it load immediately after the program has begun. I have searched for hours and not found an answer. I am not not sure as to if it should be in a class file or of the main timeline because it is a very simple variable. The point is to change the background in intervals of 640px on the press of a button or several. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am pretty new to AS3.

Thanks in advance and if anyone would like to supply sample coding that would be amazing.

Comment: where exactly you want to save your 'x' variable ? on local machine?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`SharedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) to save data to the user's machine:

```
// Grab a reference to the active SharedObject object.
var saveGame:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("SaveGame");

// Save the x and y values to your SharedObject.
saveGame.data.mcx = yourMovieClip.x;
saveGame.data.mcy = yourMovieClip.y;

// Immediately write the above changes to the local machine.
saveGame.flush();
```

Any information stored in `saveGame.data` can be collected when the user returns.

Alternatively you can send save data represented as JSON/XML/whatever to your own database via `URLLoader` and retrieve it from there.

Comment: Also, note that the first line also loads the data back into the application when you call it. From there, all your need to do is tell your movie clip's x coordinate to equal saveGame.data.mcx